# Get radio button list responses with data source asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radio button list that is inside of a asp repeater. it looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="surveyRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h3><%#((Half_Blue.Survey_files.survey_classes.surveyQuestion)Container.DataItem).questionNum%>
                . <%#((Half_Blue.Survey_files.survey_classes.surveyQuestion)Container.DataItem).question%>
        </h3>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="surveyRadioList"
            DataTextField="questionText"
            DataValueField="valueOfQuestion" runat="server"
            DataSource="<%#((Half_Blue.Survey_files.survey_classes.surveyQuestion)Container.DataItem).answerOptions %>"
            RepeatDirection="Vertical">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This displays the radio button list correctly however I cannot figure out how to get the responses in the code behind.

I can get the radio button lists by doing this:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in surveyRepeater.Items)
{
    // Checking the item is a data item
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var rdbList = item.FindControl("surveyRadioList") as RadioButtonList;
        if (rdbList != null)
        {
            retList.Add(rdbList.SelectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

however even though it finds all 8 of the radio button lists, the selected value is always just a empty "" string. The selected index is always -1 as well no matter which option I choose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are re-binding the `Repeater` on every PostBack. You need to wrap it inside an `IsPostBack` check.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    surveyRepeater.DataSource = Common.LoadFromDB();
    surveyRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

If you do not the RadioButtonLists are recreated and their selection is lost.

Comment: yep that was it. oh my god 3 hours of looking for that :P thanks so much