# How can I get selected values from radio button list and check box list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to get selected values from radio button list and check box list at asp.net, C#.
Here's my code.

### aspx.cs

```
protected void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var retList = new List<string>();

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in questionRepeater.Items)
        {
            // Checking the item is a data item
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

                var rdbList = item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1") as RadioButtonList;
                // Get the selected value
                if (rdbList != null)
                {
                    retList.Add(rdbList.SelectedValue);
                }
            }
        }


        foreach (RepeaterItem item in questionRepeater.Items)
        {
            // Checking the item is a data item
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var rdbList = item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1") as CheckBoxList;
                // Get the selected value
                if (rdbList != null)
                {
                    retList.Add(rdbList.SelectedValue);
                }
            }



        }
    }
```

### aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="questionRepeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
     <div runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("QUESTION_TYPE").ToString() == 
     "0") %>'> 
      <table style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed;">  
                <asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" CellSpacing="50" 
      TextAlign="Left" runat="server" 
      DataSource='<%#GetChild(Container.DataItem,"ChoicesRelate") %>' 
      DataTextField="CHOICES_CONTENT" DataValueField="CHOICES_NO">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
           </table> 
     </div>

     <div runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("QUESTION_TYPE").ToString() == 
     "1") %>'>
      <table style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed;">
     <asp:CheckBoxList id="CheckBoxList1" CellSpacing="50" TextAlign="Left" 
   runat="server"DataSource='<%#GetChild(Container.DataItem,"ChoicesRelate") 
   %>' DataTextField="CHOICES_CONTENT" DataValueField="CHOICES_NO">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>  
          </table>
     </div>      
    <br />
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

I refered below Answser.
[Get radio button list responses with data source asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167306/get-radio-button-list-responses-with-data-source-asp-net)

## problem

I can't get all selected values(just one value) from check box list, while I can get all from radio button list..
What should I do?
Please help me..

Comment: Ca you post the aspx code as well?

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah - Sorry, I just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
using System.Linq
...
foreach (RepeaterItem item in questionRepeater.Items)
{
    // Checking the item is a data item
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var rdbList = item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1") as CheckBoxList;
        // Get the selected value
        if (rdbList != null)
        {
            //get selected items' values 
            List<string> selectedItems = rdbList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                .Where(li => li.Selected)
                .Select(li => li.Value)
                .ToList();

            //add to your list of strings
            retList.AddRange(selectedItems);
        }
    }
}
```

or, in case you don't want to use Linq,

```
if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    var rdbList = item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1") as CheckBoxList;
    // Get the selected value
    if (rdbList != null)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in rdbList.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
                retList.Add(li.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!! this solution is for Checkbox only?  Should I keep the way get values from radio button list still?

Comment: @G.G.Sato Since `RadioButtonList` also contains collection of `ListItem`s, you can iterate through it in the same fashion

Comment: @G.G.Sato ... and, please, it this answer helped you and solved your problem, mark it as solution ;)

Comment: Wow!! That's perfectly working as I wanted!! Thanks Nino!ありがとうございます。